# How to display sparql query result in the formatted html table

Tags: sparql

How can I display the result of my sparql query into html table?. Any idea?

Comment: This is the continuation from my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092182/how-to-include-variable-in-sparql-query-using-php/1097087#1097087) for 
Tialaramax to consider to answer:
I've put the requested files as follows:

Rdf file: http://pastebin.com/me07e90f
Query form: http://pastebin.com/m719cf040
Action: http://pastebin.com/m30239388
Thanks.
Ismet

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using XSLT, you could do a transform from the [SPARQL results XML format](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-XMLres/) to HTML. If you want to build the results table with Javascript, you may prefer to use the [JSON results format](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-json-res/).

Comment: sorry. not really understand what you mean. I have the above code which still can't carry the variable into sparql query (Still looking at it). The result that display in the code can't be modified. I want them to be displayed into HTML table that I am going to create.

Answer (score 0):

Joseki includes such transformation xlst by default. I think the license is Apache so you can use it.